# Filtering out internal points in 3D mesh

Tags: math, 3d, mesh

I have a program that does analysis on 3D shapes only if all the vertices are on the surface of the shape. However, the data I am provided with has vertices on the inside so I need a way to filter them out.

The data is given in the following format:

A list of all the vertices (i.e their coordinates), each vertex has a ID so it can be identified.

A list of tetrahedrons where each tetrahedron is defined by four vertices (using the IDs).

So basically a face from each tetrahedron forms part of the surface and the rest of the tetrahedron forms part of the internal structure (which is not important to me).

Looking at the rendered shape one can identify the internal points unambiguously so I'm assuming that there is some property of the internal points that I can use to filter them out but I can't think of one.

Can anyone think of a method to solve this problem of identifying internal points?

Thanks.

Comment: An internal face is is a triangle between two tetrahedra, an internal vertex is one neighboring only internal faces. This should work

Comment: Can the tetrahedrons overlap?

Comment: No, I don't think so (I didn't write the data files so I can't be positive).

Comment: @JanDvorak: I think this might work. I'll try this and respond with my results.